# Изменить налог через woocommerce_before_calculate_totals

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Пытаюсь изменить налог для пользователя, который заполнит поле "tax". Но почему-то налог не меняется.
Хотя при использовании такого условия с дефолтным полем города WC()->customer->get_billing_city() == 'xxx'), все изменятся.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_items_tax_prices', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_items_tax_prices( $cart  ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    if ( WC()->customer->get_billing_city() == 'xxx') {
        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
            if ($product_id==11) {
                $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'Test' );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Какая может быть ошибка?